# iOS: How to Backup a Project?

Tags: ios, file, resources, backup, project

What's the best way to backup a project?

To be more specific: I have a DropBox account and I prefer to have a copy of the project over there.

I assume I should copy all the h+m files.

Can I copy all the xib files? does it make any sense?

Can/Should I copy all the jpg/png/mp3 files that I use for resources?

Is there a proper way to do that, like a "backup project" button where I can select the target and it compresses the project in some smart way?

Comment: you really should look into source control.

Answer (score 1):

You need all of those and the project files, etc.  Look in the project file to see all files referenced.  Check to see if you have everything by making a copy and trying to build from the copy.  You'll get complaints if you missed any thing.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing is to copy the entire directory where all your project exists. Copy this directory to your dropbox folder. To open the project open yourproject.xcodeproj with xcode.

Although this method is okay for one time thing or when you are the only one working on your project but in the long run you should look at trying to adopt a source control versioning system like [GIT](http://git-scm.com/). [Xcode](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/23/using-git-versioning-inside-your-xcode-project/) has wonderful integration with GIT.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to backup a project is source control.  There are many options available to get free or very cheap remote source control repositories where you can store a copy (and history) of your source.  Checkout http://www.beanstalkapp.com or http://www.github.com for a start.